# PHP get input from different page

Tags: php, html

So this is not the typical get post from one page to another.

Basically I have a password reset function on my website so user will enter their email address on one page, they get an email with a reset link which has a token at the end of it and when they open that link, it just asks them for their New Password and to Confirm New Password and Submit, that is all, email is not used/referenced on this page at all. It works fine for it's initial purpose but now I am integrating an XML service endpoint into this so when a customer resets their password on the New Password Screen, it will update their password as well on the XML service endpoint but requires their email to login to that account in order to update the password which I cannot get to work.

I have tried _Session and _Post and _Get but nothing seems to work as it is not exactly the same session as the "Email" page as opposed to the "New Password", "Confirm New Password" page.

There are backend pages to these two, forgotten.php in controller which basically just references what the pre-defined languages are ex. (entry_email is referenced to another php file which would be $entry_email = "Please enter your email address:"

Then another page for model which points and makes the updates/changes/queries to the MySQL DB.

Request Email Page:

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
<div id="content">
    <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
    <div class="warning"><?php echo $error_warning; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
  <div class="content-title">
    <h1><?php echo $content_title; ?></h1>
  </div>
  <form action="index.php?route=account/forgotten" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <center><p><?php echo $text_email; ?></p></center>
    <div class="content">
    <h2><?php echo $text_your_email; ?></h2>
      <table class="form">
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $entry_email; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
        <div class="page_buttons">
          <a href="<?php echo $back; ?>" class="button b_left"><?php echo $button_back; ?></a>
          <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_submit; ?>" class="button b_right" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
  <div id="placeholder"></div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Enter New Password and Confirm Page:

```
<div id="content">
    <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
        <div class="warning"><?php echo $error_warning; ?></div>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <div class="content-title">
        <h1><?php echo $reset_content_title; ?></h1>
      </div>
      <form action="index.php?route=account/forgotten/reset" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="content">
        <h2><?php echo $reset_content_title; ?></h2>
          <table class="form">
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $entry_password; ?></td>
              <td><input type="password" name="password" value="" />
                <?php if ($error_password) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_password; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td><input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_GET['token'];?>" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $entry_confirm; ?></td>
              <td><input type="password" name="confirm" value="" />
                <?php if ($error_confirm) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_confirm; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <div class="page_buttons">
            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_reset; ?>" class="button b_right" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
  <div id="placeholder"></div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

MySQL query on submit:

```
    public function editPasswordByToken($token, $password) {
    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "customer SET cus_code ='',                        cus_password = '" . $this->db->escape(sha1($password)) . "' WHERE cus_code = '" . $this->db->escape($token) . "' LIMIT 1 ");
}
    public function getCustomerByToken($token) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE cus_code = '" . $this->db->escape($token) . "' LIMIT 1 ");

    return $query->row;
}
```

Public Function Reset() code:

```
        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->resetvalidate()) {

        $this->submitMiva();  

        $this->model_account_customer->editPasswordByToken($this->request->post['token'], $this->request->post['password']); 

        $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_reset_success');

        //$this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
    }
```

Comment: In the page where the user is changing their password, surely you know who the user *is* when processing the submit from that page?  Can't you determine their email address based on knowing who they are?

Comment: Yes, so when they submit their New Password and Confirm New Password, it basically does a Update in MySQL where the Token matches with the customers account. I tried creating a separate MySQL query to get the email address where the token matches but does not work and shows up as blank when I do an Echo but when I used the same method in python, it successfully pulled the email address.

Comment: `"I tried creating a separate MySQL query to get the email address where the token matches but does not work and shows up as blank"` - *That* sounds like a bug to be corrected, and one with which we can help given information about the problem.  But I can't imagine how you can be updating a user's password without knowing who the user is...

Comment: I updated the original post with more code as to how it is getting that customer based off their token used